# CDF of a density function with absolute value, given bounds for $X$

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I am trying to find the CDF of A continuous random variable $X$ and I am having trouble coming up with the bounds for the integral.

$f_X(x) = \frac{|x|}{\frac{5}{2}} $, where $ -2 \leq x \leq 1$. 0 otherwise.

My first thought was to split the cases up with the first case being

Case 1: $x < -2$

$\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(x) dx =\int_{-\infty}^{x} 0 dx = 0 $

Case 2: $ -2 \leq x \leq 1$

Case 3: $x > 1$

I am stuck on how to do the 2nd and 3rd case. Do I first split the absolute value up within case 2? Or is there a 4th case?

Comment: What are you trying to find? The question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When absolute value is involved, a split at the sign change is helpful.

$$\begin{align}f_X(x)&=\begin{cases}\tfrac 25\lvert x\rvert &:& -2\leqslant x\leqslant 1\\0&:& \text{elsewise}\end{cases}\\[1ex] &=\begin{cases}-\tfrac 25x &:& -2\leqslant x<0\\[1ex]~~~\tfrac 25 x&:& ~~~0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\\~~~0&:& \text{elsewise}\end{cases}\\[2ex]F_X(x)&=\begin{cases}0 &:& x< -2\\[1ex]\displaystyle\int_{-2}^x -\tfrac 25s~\mathrm d s&:& -2\leqslant x<0\\[1ex]\displaystyle\int_{-2}^0 -\tfrac 25s~\mathrm d s+\int_0^x \tfrac 25s~\mathrm d s&:& 0\leqslant x< 1\\[1ex]1&:& 1\leqslant x\end{cases}\\[1ex]&~~\ddots\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You should split up what you call case 2 in two cases:

- $-2\leq x<0$. Then $\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(u)du=\frac25\int_{-2}^x-udu$
- $0\leq x\leq1$. Then $\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(u)du=\frac25\int_{-2}^0-udu+\frac25\int_0^x udu$

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured it out.

Comment: The 4 Cases are:
Case 1: $x < -2$
Then $f_x(t) = 0$ for all $t \leq x$.

\\
Therefore
$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_x(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x} 0$ dt = 0.
\\

Case 2: $ -2 \leq x < 0$
Then $f_x(t) = \frac{x}{\frac{5}{2}}$ for all $-2 \leq t \leq x$.

Therefore $F_X(x) = \int_{-2}^{x} f_x(t) dt = \int_{-2}^{x} \frac{t}{\frac{5}{2}}$ dt = $\frac{2}{5}\int_{-2}^{x} -t$ dt$ = \frac{2}{5}*-\frac{t^2}{2}\Big|_{-2}^x$ = 
$\frac{2}{5} \Big(-\frac{x^2}{2}+2\Big)$

Comment: Case 3: $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$. Then $f_x(t) = \frac{t}{\frac{5}{2}}$ for all $ 0 \leq t \leq x$.

Therefore $F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(t) dt = \frac{2}{5}\Big( \int_{-2}^{0} -(t) dt + \int_{0}^{x} t dt\Big)$ = $\frac{2}{5}\Big(2+\frac{x^2}{2}\Big)$
\\

Case 4: $ x > 1 $.
Then $f_x(t) = 0$ for all $ 1 \leq t \leq x$. Therefore $F_x(x) = F_x(1) + \int_{1}^{x} f_x(t) dt = \frac{2}{5}\Big(2+\frac{1^2}{2}\Big) + \int_{1}^{x} 0$ dt = $\Big(\frac{2}{5} * \frac{5}{2}\Big) + 0 = 1 + 0 = 1$.

Comment: Looks fine to me.